# Different methods of website layouts with HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

This is more of a "best practices" question. I'm doing some front-end web development and right now when I place elements (text, button, etc) I literally do everything by pixel, and append it to a main div element. Here's an example:

```
var button = document.createElement('input');
button.type = "button";
button.value = "Click Me";
button.style.position = "absolute";
button.style.top = "200px";
button.style.left = "150px";
mainDiv.appendChild(button);
```

...And I'm doing like every element this way, and it's starting to feel wrong (was really easy at first, but now if I want to change a layout by adding/removing elements, I have to change like 50 numbers from element positions). Also, I'm not sure if specifying exact pixel locations is good when it comes to cross-browser (and screen resolution) compatibility.

I'd much rather have a way where elements are positioned more relative to each other, so adding in one new element doesn't mean I have to reposition everything else.

Could you guys help point me in the right direction for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, first... Checkout jQuery. My second comment is, you must come from the print world... :P

Comment: I'd be more inclined to try to include as many of the elements as you can in your HTML, position them with CSS, and then dynamically hide and show them with JS rather than creating them from JS. Much easier to test the layout, and much easier to add or remove things without having to update everything else. Should be much easier to get the tab order working right too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to use HTML to define the semantics of your page and use CSS to position and style it..

So if you want to move one button 10px from the one above it:

```
<input type="button" id="button1">
<input type="button" id="button2">

#button1 { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

This really is a really broad question - you need basic HTML and CSS.

Comment: Just a note: the above will work if you add `input { display: block; }` to the CSS. Otherwise, the buttons will display side-by-side, and the margin-bottom will not be visible.

Comment: I do have basic HTML and CSS, I just happen to do a lot of it dynamically from JavaScript to respond to user events and database submissions, etc. My main question is moving away from pixel-based positioning to more relative positioning.

Comment: So you can make elements move farther away from each other using margin.  You can add space around an element using padding.  The rest of the layout problems comes down to the difference between whether something is display: block or not.  Block elements can take on shapes and effect its neighbors. Inline elements (like span) dont.